# Windows Process Activation Service fails to start on Windows 7

Tags: web-services, iis, iis-7

I'm attempting to setup a website for local testing. But when I try to start the site in IIS, I get the error

> Web sites cannot be started unless both the Windows Activation Service(WAS) and World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC) are running. Both services are currently stopped.

I then attempted to start WAS service  manually and received the error

> Windows could not start the Windows Process Activation Service service on Local Computer.  Error 6831: The encryption operation could not be completed because a transaction is active.

Looking at the windows event logs, I notice an additional error

> The Windows Process Activation Service failed to generate an application pool config file for application pool '*'. The error type is '0'. To resolve this issue, please ensure that the applicationhost.config file is correct and recommit the last configuration changes made. The data field contains the error number.

I checked the applicationhost.config file for errors and see nothing that appears to be incorrect, verified the xml isn't malformed, verified all paths in the config file exist, gave full access permission to the inetpub folder to all users, and checked the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\WAS` for paths that may be incorrect.

I have no idea what else to do to get my site up and running.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Usually that's caused by broken permissions and user rights, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/981949/description-of-default-permissions-and-user-rights-for-iis-7-0-and-lat You might start by reviewing each.

Comment: Can also be caused by an incorrect folder in C:\inetpub\temp\appPools, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46742076/iis-app-pool-and-was-stop-automatically-with-with-event-id-5189